# MySQL Stored Procedure | How to write it?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This time I have a MySQL question, I'm trying to create a stored procedure which will execute a prepared statement, the goal is to get a ranged list from a table("`order_info`"), the list is divided by "pages", each page is determined by a record count and should be ordered using a particular field sorted either `'ASC'` or `'DESC'`, each record represents an "`order`" the catch here is that the procedure returns the orders of a particular group, the the order is associated to a `user` which belongs to a `group`. Here's what I've done so far:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getGroupOrders`(IN grp INT,
                                                   IN page INT, 
                                                   IN count INT, 
                                                   IN ord TINYINT, 
                                                   IN srt VARCHAR(4)
                                                   )
    BEGIN
        PREPARE prepGroupOrders FROM
        "SELECT oi.* FROM `dbre`.`order_info` oi
            INNER JOIN `dbre`.`users` usr 
            ON oi.`username` = usr.`username` AND usr.`id_group` = ?
            ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?";

        SET @g := grp;
        SET @cnt := count;
        SET @start := @page*count ;
        SET @orderBy := ord;
        SET @sortBy := srt;

        EXECUTE prepGroupOrders USING @g,@orderBy,@sortBy,@start,@cnt;
    END
```

I get a syntax error when executing this, even though the editor does not higlight any errors and lets me save the procedure,I think that one of the follwing may be happening:

- I am incorrectly usng the `ASC` or `DESC` since it is a SQL reserved word.
- I read somewhere that Prepared statement are for only ONE SQL query, and since I have nested queries it can't be done.

I've tested this standard query:

```
    SELECT oi.* FROM `dbre`.`order_info` oi
        INNER JOIN `dbre`.`users` usr
        ON oi.`username` = usr.`username` AND usr.`id_group` = 1
    ORDER BY `status` DESC LIMIT 5, 10;
```

And it gives me the results I want. SO how would I design the procedure?
Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Ok, so I've found a way to use the ordering but still no hope on the sorting, since the place holder functions only for values and not identifiers, the `ORDER BY` can use the column index instead of passing a `VARCHAR(10)` as identifier.

Answer (score 0):

This may not necessarily solve your issue but, you can probably clean that query up a bit, eliminate the subquery and get something that should perform a little better.

```
SELECT oi.* 
    FROM `dbre`.`order_info` oi
        INNER JOIN  `dbre`.`users` u
            ON oi.username = u.username
                AND u.id_group = 1
    ORDER BY `status` DESC 
    LIMIT 5, 10;
```

Comment: Thank you, I too was considering of optimizing the sub-query, but I wasn't sure how to do it using joins, I have a question on your query, what does `oi` and `u` I think its an alias, correct me if I'm wrong. Also, is as join always better than a sub-query?

Comment: 1. Yes, `oi` and `u` are aliases for the tables. 2. Depends on how good your indexes are and how "smart" the optimizer is but, in general, the subquery will return a larger result set than what is needed to satisfy the equivalent join, resulting in more reads from the database.